# How to setup NEAR blockchain project in vs code

Tags: blockchain, nearprotocol

Now I want to create a project in NEAR blockchain using javascript. I'm following with this code

1. npm init
2. npm install
3. npm install npx
4. npx create-near-app@latest
   when I'm executing last "npx create-near-app@latest" command in vs code terminal it showing an error "Notice: On Win32 please use WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)." but i have already intall ubuntu 22.04 LTS version. so how to fix it?.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngcMe.png)

PS D:\Near> npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See `npm help init` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg>` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
package name: (near) cls
version: (1.0.0)
description:
entry point: (index.js)
test command:
git repository:
keywords:
author:
PS D:\Near> npm install

up to date, audited 1 package in 47ms
found 0 vulnerabilities
PS D:\Near> npm install npx

added 1 package, and audited 494 packages in 9s

1 package is looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

50 vulnerabilities (1 low, 20 moderate, 19 high, 10 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

## Run `npm audit` for details.
PS D:\Near> npx create-near-app@latest

## Welcome to NEAR! Learn more: https://docs.near.org/
 Let's get your dApp ready.

(NEAR collects anonymous information on the commands used. No personal information that could identify you is shared)

Notice: On Win32 please use WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install
Exiting now.
PS D:\Near>